# Can we turn on YouTube video embedding?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I would appreciate it if we could embed YouTube clips to explain ideas and concepts, rather than linking them externally. It makes the explaining a little more interactive and less fragmented. I think some of the SE sites have this enabled but I don't think it's been done here.

Comment: I second it. Is this associated with the site's graduation?

Comment: @Farhan No, it's not associated with site graduation. It's just a flag we flip on our end. I'm bringing this up to the community team to look into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can certainly enable YouTube embedding assuming there is a need for it. Over on Movies & TV (a natural candidate for the feature), we asked the community to [list posts](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/631/video-embedding-for-movies-se) that could benefit from embedding video. Because text searches ([primarily via Google](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260849/proposed-micro-privilege-site-analytics)) provide much of the traffic to Stack Exchange sites, it's important that video *supplement* the content of posts. For instance, it probably makes sense to embed videos to provide visual evidence of the veracity of an answer that's already been fleshed out in words.

I looked at a few of the [top voted post that link to YouTube](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=votes&q=url%3a*youtube.com*) and also some from the ["most relevant"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=url%3a*youtube.com*) sort. From that sample I think enabling embedded videos would likely be beneficial here. Not all of those posts would need more than a link, but some would definitely look better on this site if the reader didn't have to follow a link to another page.

I'm planning to turn this on sometime next week unless there are any objections.

Comment: Did you have time to turn it on? I couldn't seem to get it working right now...

Comment: @MikeFoxtrot: Could you try now? I changed the setting.

Comment: Nope, no luck on [this one](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17672/why-does-the-speed-tape-on-the-lockheed-u-2-go-the-opposite-way) (unless I'm doing it wrong of course)

Comment: Or wait, had to save it to see it :D thanks

Comment: @MikeFoxtrot: Interesting question. It's sorta shocking there is a video on YouTube showing the interior of a U2. (And I'm glad embedding worked for you.)